# LinkingObjects in react-native realm

Tags: reactjs, react-native, realm

I am currently trying to get the Realm Database for my react-native Application working, but I am unable to create a link between two Objects.

I am able to fetch Objects, I am able to create single Objects, but I am unable to link two Objects together

I followed the documentation, specifically I am looking at creating a [Inverse Relationship](https://realm.io/docs/javascript/latest/#inverse-relationships)

```
class PersonSchema {
  public static schema: Realm.ObjectSchema = {
    name: 'Person',
    primaryKey: 'id',
    properties: {
      id: 'string',
      username: 'string',
      dogs: 'Dog[]',
      },
   };
 }
class DogSchema {
  public static schema: Realm.ObjectSchema = {
    name: 'Dog',
    primaryKey: 'id',
    properties: {
      id: 'string',
      name: 'string',
      owner: {type: 'linkingObjects', objectType: 'Person', property: 'dogs'},
    },
  };
}
```

I open my Realm with both schemas

```
  componentDidMount() {
    Realm.open({
      schema: [PersonSchema.schema, DogSchema.schema],
      deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded: true,
    }).then(realm => {
      this.setState({realm});
    });
  }
```

One thing I tried was the following:

```
createPerson = () => {
    const id = uuid();
    const personenName = 'Steve ' + id;
    const realm = this.state.realm;
    if (realm) {
      realm.write(() => {
        const dog = realm.create('Dog', {
          id,
          name: 'Bello ' + id,
        });
        const dogs = realm.objects('Dog');
        const person = realm.create('Person', {
          id,
          username: personenName,
          dogs: [],
        });
        const persons = realm.objects('Person');
        person.dogs.push(dog);
      });
    }
  };
```

But I also tried linking the Dog to the Person. I tried creating a Dog and in that call create a Person for him and vice versa ... All tries throw an Error. The above Code just freezes the App.

How do I properly link two Objects together ?

For my App I want to link stuff to the User so I can look it up faster.